# Unity raw image cordinates to world cordinates

Tags: unity-game-engine, user-interface

I am in a 2d unity Project. I have a raw image that displays what a camera see's. If I hower with my mouse over  a object that is displayed on the raw image, how can I get the world position of that object?

I am in a 2d unity Project. I am filming a object with a Camera. The Target Texture is projected on a Render Texture. The Render Texture is projected on a Raw image in the ui.
Now my question is: if I hover with my mouse over the object, that is displayed on the Raw Image, how can I get the position of that object in World space?

I think to solve the Probleme you need to use the ratio between the scale of the raw image and the camera that is filming the content of the raw image. And then also the position of the raw image on screen.

[Game view](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7VUQ8.png)

Comment: You can get the uv coordinates of the render texture by raycasting from your main camera and using the [hit.textureCoord](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/RaycastHit-textureCoord.html).  From there cast an additional ray through your render texture camera (using `ViewportPointToRay(uvCoord)`) to get the world point from that RaycastHit.  I have done something similar in 3d, it should work in 2d but I cannot confirm.

Comment: https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/RectTransformUtility.ScreenPointToLocalPointInRectangle.html .. which should then be the "screen point" of that according camera => https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Camera.ScreenPointToRay.html with the previous result should allow to hit the 3D object